# odoo security restrict company from opening general setting

Tags: python-3.x, security, odoo, odoo-12

I installed a custom odoo module to add a total and line discount to orders it working well till I added a new company, after adding a new company I must go to invoicing to activate total discount but odoo restrict me form doing that

I tried to add rules but it doesn't work. I don't know what actually rule I shoud add

This is how I defined the setting view

```
class KSResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'res.config.settings'

    ks_enable_discount = fields.Boolean(string="Activate Total Discount")
    ks_sales_discount_account = fields.Many2one('account.account', string="Sales Discount Account")
    ks_purchase_discount_account = fields.Many2one('account.account', string="Purchase Discount Account")
    ks_accounting_present = fields.Boolean(compute='ks_check_charts_of_accounts')

    def get_values(self):
        ks_res = super(KSResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        ks_res.update(
            ks_enable_discount=self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('ks_enable_discount'),
        ks_sales_discount_account=int(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('ks_sales_discount_account')),
        ks_purchase_discount_account=int(self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('ks_purchase_discount_account')),)
        return ks_res

    def set_values(self):
        super(KSResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('ks_enable_discount', self.ks_enable_discount)
        if self.ks_enable_discount:
            self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('ks_sales_discount_account', self.ks_sales_discount_account.id)
            self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('ks_purchase_discount_account',
                                                      self.ks_purchase_discount_account.id)
```

```
odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="ks_res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">ks.res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.account.discount</field>
            <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="50"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='has_accounting_entries']" position="after">

                    <h2 attrs="{'invisible': [('has_chart_of_accounts','==',False)]}">Total Discount</h2>
                    <div class="row mt16 o_settings_container"
                         attrs="{'invisible': [('has_chart_of_accounts','==',False)]}">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 o_setting_box">
                            <div class="o_setting_left_pane">
                                <field name="ks_enable_discount"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                                <label for ='ks_enable_discount'/>
                                <div class="text-muted">
                                    Activate Total discount on all modules.
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 o_setting_box" attrs="{'invisible':[('ks_enable_discount','==',False)]}">
                            <div class="o_setting_left_pane"/>
                            <div class="o_setting_right_pane">
                                <span class="o_form_label">Accounts</span>
                                <div class="text-muted">
                                        Set default Total discount accounts for sale and purchase order.
                                </div>
                                <div class="content-group">
                                    <div class="row mt16" >
                                        <label for="ks_sales_discount_account"
                                               class="col-md-3 o_light_label"/>
                                        <field name="ks_sales_discount_account"
                                               attrs="{'required': [('ks_enable_discount','==',True)]}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt16" >
                                        <label for="ks_purchase_discount_account"
                                               class="col-md-3 o_light_label"/>
                                        <field name="ks_purchase_discount_account"
                                               attrs="{'required': [('ks_enable_discount','==',True)]}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

This what appears in log

2019-10-29 12:31:26,410 16582 INFO demo odoo.models: The requested operation cannot be completed due to record rules: Document type: account.account, Operation: read, Records: 31, User: 2[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this error is occuring because this module is not multi-company supported

ks_sales_discount_account = fields.Many2one('account.account', string="Sales Discount Account")

ks_purchase_discount_account = fields.Many2one('account.account', string="Purchase Discount

These fields are occuring problem when we set this field in one company and we go to other company we can't access same account and that is occuring problem values are set for those field and user tried to access those accounts but he don't have permission for that.

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: You can't use this module for multi-company you have to reconfigure the full module.